# DirectX11 dynamic vertex buffer-mapping misses data when calling multiple times

Tags: c++, directx-11, terrain

So i am implementing terrain and at run-time implementing different techniques such as fault line, diamond-square

I have subgrids that are responsible for culling sections out and basically when performing one of the algorithms i loop through the sections and map the vertex buffer and then update the positions and finally unmap

I notice if i press twice fast the keyboard input which triggers the algorithms parts of the mesh dissappear and end up with weird values that are as if they are uninitialised. I solve this by putting a small timer around the call which on my laptop is 0.4sec

I put my project onto a uni computer and i was able to take the timer right down to almost 0 wait and the algorithm worked perfectly without any loss of data

so my question is can anyone give me info about mapping and unmapping and why im assuming my GPU is possibly slower to make the changes

thanks

Comment: To make sure I get you correctly. So when you press the button twice, does the buffer get mapped twice without being unmapped for the press before?

Comment: Hey, no so the flow definitely goes as follows ( gets input key -> calls Algorithm -> Update -> Draw) if you press the button twice it doesnt do it straight away its like the next cycle